# Unexisting margins

Tags: jquery, html, css, margin

I'm working on some layout made from squares, their width is defined by percentages and height by padding the same as width for 1:1 aspect, and using jQuery Masonry for positioning them. The problem is that some like margins started showing up, there is no padding nor margins set to them, but after re sizing window they disappear, here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/uvrcpuag/3/embedded/result/

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
</div>

.square {
    width: 16.666666666666666666666666666667%;
    padding-bottom: 16.666666666666666666666666666667%;
    background-color: #000;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Do you want gaps or margins?

Comment: No, everything should be pure black, without gaps or margin, like after re sizing window.

Comment: The only solution that I found was adding `.resize()` as shown by Rohan Kumar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to trigger manually `resize()` like,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var msnry = new Masonry('#container', {
        itemSelector: '.square'
    }).resize();  // call resize()  
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/uvrcpuag/7/embedded/result/)